# Node module property how to exposed and update

Tags: javascript, node.js

i've node app  and I've created a module/file to restore some global value via event that update the value and return it, when I use it I always get false even the event was called,How I can do it right ?
I want it to behave like getter property,

global.js file

```
var inter = require("../pl/intr");
var isAvailable;

inter.eventEmitter.on('AppAvailable', function () {
    console.log("---events is raised--");
    isAvailable = true;
});

module.exports = {
    isAvailable:isAppAvailable
}
```

I checked the event and the console.log was called...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does this do what you need?

```
var inter = require("../pl/intr");
module.exports = {isAvaiable:false};

inter.eventEmitter.on('AppAvailable', function () {
    console.log("---events is raised--");
    module.exports.isAvailable = true;
});
```

Comment: Thanks but why I need to do the exports twice, there is not nicer way to do that?

Comment: var a=true; var b = a; /*now b is true*/ a=false; /*value of b didn't change, it is still true*/

Comment: In your original example, you create exports object with property isAvaialbe=false; but then you don't change this property, you change the local isAvaialbe. Also note that module.exports doesn't need to be object, you can do module.exports=false; and then module.exports=true

Comment: Thanks but lets say I've additional boolean properties in this module, I cannot just export false/true, how you suggest to do it?

Comment: Just like I suggested in my answer. module.exports={isAvaiable:false, anotherProperty:"I am a string", pi:3.14}